# .NET classes and their source code

Tags: c#, .net

When I'm writing a C# (or any .NET programme) I use methods and classes. Most of the code I use is calling methods from the .NET classes. Is it possible (purely out of curiosity) to see the actual source code for these classes?

I know MSDN has full listings of the classes, their properties and their methods. But I would like to see the code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Yes, it is](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/):

> Browse the [.NET Framework](http://msdn.com/net) source code online, with search and navigation powered by [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn).
>
> See details at the [.NET Framework blog](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=389985)...

Comment: Unfortunately, as of Jan 2022 this is still .NET 4.8.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible. See here for more info:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/16/net-framework-library-source-code-now-available.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can also run a disassembler (such as the one in Reflector) over the base class libraries and view code that way, if you don't want to configure your dev environment.  You won't get real variable names or comments, but for isolated viewing this can be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Microsoft has released the source .NET.

[This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx) should help get you started.

Answer (score 0):

The link mentioned in the accepted answer (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/) only contains .NET source up to version 4.8. Development is now done on Github, where you can find (literally) up-to-the-minute versions of the source files.

The [`dotnet`](https://github.com/dotnet) Github organization (the .NET Foundation) has many of the repos relating to .NET, including [`core`](https://github.com/dotnet/core), the CLR [runtime](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime), [`aspnetcore`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore), and a bunch of others. Most of the source code is organized into Visual Studio projects and solutions, so you can import them easily.